# How to create PSTNusages via PowerShell in Skype for Busin server

Tags: skype-for-business

How to create PSTNusages via PowerShell in Skype for Busin server. There is an option in GUI but no PowerShell cmdlet  for the same. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Set-CsPstnUsage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/set-cspstnusage?view=skype-ps) and [Get-CsPstnUsage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/get-cspstnusage?view=skype-ps)

See links for examples on how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set just use the following CMD in Skype for business management shell:

```
Set-CsPstnUsage -Identity global -Usage @{Add = } -Verbose
```